# Exception SIGSTOP

Tags: objective-c, exception, avaudioplayer

I am new to XCode and Objective-C. I have this exception poppin' up when I let the app run in the simulator. On the iPad it works fine. When the AVaudioPlayer is allocated I have a stop with the warning SIGSTOP.

Anybody have any suggestions? Is this a serious exception? Thanks in advance!

I dont know where to find the 'stack trace' so I put RUN debugger to gdb:
the info from this:
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""soundScape.m":112" resolved
rndmitem
amount
url

The lines before SIGSTOP are:

libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw:
0x46e4a44:  pushl  %ebp
0x46e4a45:  movl   %esp, %ebp

Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
0x1 does not appear to point to a valid object.
0x2 does not appear to point to a valid object.
file://localhost/Users/myName/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/E92E5F03-0B07-4AF0-BFB4-E1F7009A4E78/babyschets.app/02Seawash.mp3
[Switching to process 81163 thread 0x1720b]
[Switching to process 81163 thread 0x15803]

under Exception State Registers:
trapno = (unsigned int) 0x000003
err = (unsigned int) 0x000000
faultvaddr = (unsigned int) 0x087df732


This happens for example when the values are the following:

**randomItem** :
(NSUInteger) $0 = 1 [no Objective-C description available]
**amountOfAudioFiles** : 
(int) $1 = 2 [no Objective-C description available]
**url** : 
(NSURL *) $2 = 0x07485860 
file://localhost/Users/myName/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/E92E5F03-0B07-4AF0-BFB4-E1F7009A4E78/babyschets.app/02Seawash.mp3

**audioFiles1**: 
(NSArray *) $4 = 0x0747d720 <__NSArrayI 0x747d720>(
01Seawash.mp3,
02Seawash.mp3
)

```
int amountOfAudioFiles = [audioFiles1 count];
NSUInteger randomItem = arc4random()%(int)amountOfAudioFiles;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:[NSString stringWithString:[audioFiles1 objectAtIndex:randomItem]]
                                     ofType:nil]];

NSError *error;

audioPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
```

Ok I have cleaned this code here are my solutions. Now it is running like a charm:

in the .h file:
     @property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer1;

in the .m file:

```
int amountOfAudioFiles = [audioFiles1 count];
int randomItem = (int)(arc4random()%amountOfAudioFiles);
if (randomItem < 0) randomItem = 0;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [audioFiles1 objectAtIndex:randomItem]]
                                     ofType:nil]];


if (audioPlayer1) {
    if (audioPlayer1.isPlaying) {
        [audioPlayer1 stop];
        audioPlayer1 = nil;
    }

} else {
    audioPlayer1 = [AVAudioPlayer alloc];
}

NSError *error;
audioPlayer1 = [audioPlayer1 initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
```

Comment: When your app crash in XCode, usually the debugger/console show you a stack trace with details of the error. Is there anything there you could show us?

Comment: `SIGSTOP` is an unusual signal - that's normally used for job control in the terminal (i.e. `Ctrl-Z` and later `fg`)!

Answer (score 0):

This means that the Object(in a framework) is not present in the iOS version.
Perhaps u need to update the iOS of ur iOS device in which u r testing/running the App.

Comment: My simulator is 5.1. Isn't this up-to-date?

Comment: try the code on a real iOS device.. preferably with iOS 5.1.1, ur AV object seem causing the crash in the Simulator